# How to create custom validator with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular 2 and I want to create a custom validator which handles multiple regex for input fields.

I think I can't use `pattern` attribute because there are multiple regex values.

Is there any way to call `my_Custom_Validator` as custom validator?

```
<input id="xbd4msjgn" type="text" [(ngModel)]="xbd4msjgn">
```

Here is javascript side;

```
export class MyComponent {

   private xbd4msjgn;

   my_Custom_Validator(){

      if(checkRegex1()){
        showErrorMessageForRegex1();
      }
      if(checkRegex2()){
        showErrorMessageForRegex2();
      }

   }


}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Comment: @R.Richards I don't want to validate when user submit form but I want to validate instantly when user types.

Answer (score 1):

> You can do something like this:

```
 private customValidator(control: AbstractControl): { invalid: boolean } {
    const regExp1 = /^[a-z\A-Z\s-\.]+$/;
    const regExp2 = /^[a-z\A-Z\s-\.]+$/;
    if (!regExp1.test(control.value)) {
        return {invalid: true};
    } else if (!regExp2.test(control.value)) {
        return {invalid: true};
    }
}
```